# Running interactive bat file from java?

Tags: java, batch-file

Need help to call batch file from java which is interactive and it should not be opened in the new window. Tried to call using Runtime --- cmd /c start batchfilename --- But it is opening in new window. I need to focus and execution of the calling batch file in the same window from where it is being called.

Comment: Please write some code of that Program which executes `Runtime` .

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a start command:

```
C:\>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
      [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
      [/AFFINITY <hex affinity>] [/WAIT] [/B] [command/program]
      [parameters]

    "title"     Title to display in  window title bar.
    path        Starting directory
    B           Start application without creating a new window. The
                application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
                enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
                the application
    I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
                to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
    MIN         Start window minimized
    MAX         Start window maximized
    SEPARATE    Start 16-bit Windows program in separate memory space
    SHARED      Start 16-bit Windows program in shared memory space
    LOW         Start application in the IDLE priority class
    NORMAL      Start application in the NORMAL priority class
    HIGH        Start application in the HIGH priority class
    REALTIME    Start application in the REALTIME priority class
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Try to run start (and not cmd). If that does'nt help you may catch user in/output and pipe to the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29).